# Using sed to replace bracketed content even if multiple nested ones

Tags: sed, brackets

I am using `sed` to find and delete text expression with opening and closing brackets in it.

Example: `sed -re 's/ SCYEXIT\([^)]+\)//g'`

Works with empty brackets: `SCYEXIT(' ')`
But some of my text lines have two pair of boxed brackets and the search above fails.

Failing example: `SCYEXIT('/var/mqm/exits/SecExitSender(SecurityExit)')` 
The result is: `')`

Some of the brackets are empty `(' ')`
or have content `('FN=/var/mqm/exits/sendexit.data')`
or even have another pair of brackets in it 
like `('/var/mqm/exits/SecExitSender(SecurityExit)')`.

How can i handle all matching brackets?

To make things more clear.

I am migrating IBM MQ from one platform to another and there are some differences in the parameters for each platforms. An example of a config looks like this:

`DEFINE QLOCAL ('postcard') SCYEXIT('/var/mqm/exits/SecExitSender(SecurityExit)') PROCESS(' ') PUT(ENABLED) DEFPRTY(0) REPLACE`

Here I want to get rid of `SCYEXIT` and `PROCESS` attribute independent of the content of the following pair of brackets. You as human understand immediately what I mean with the bracket here. The brackets can be empty, or have a value or even a nested value in it.

The result that I want to achieve is this:

`DEFINE QLOCAL ('postcard') PUT(ENABLED) DEFPRTY(0) REPLACE`

Comment: you need to give more details on your data, like are there text after the closing `)`  and can that data contain `)`?

Comment: Yes @"sp asic", the is text after the closing bracket.
An example snippet:
DEFINE CHANNEL ('1234567890') CHLTYPE(RCVR)        TRPTYPE(TCP)          BATCHSZ(50)          DESCR(' ')        HBINT(300)          MAXMSGL(4194304)          MCAUSER(' ')        MRDATA(' ')        MREXIT(' ')        MRRTY(10)          MRTMR(1000)          MSGDATA(' ')        MSGEXIT(' ')        NPMSPEED(FAST)          PUTAUT(DEF)          RCVDATA(' ')        RCVEXIT(' ')        SCYDATA(' ')        SCYEXIT('/var/mqm/exits/SecExitSender(SecurityExit)')                  REPLACE

Comment: and does that text contain `)` ? if not, try `sed 's/ SCYEXIT(.*)//g'`

Comment: This was my first idea but then i realized that it eats then all text to the last bracket. 
So this is not the solution. 
I need only to the first closing bracket.
But if there is **another** opening bracket then i have to take the second closing bracket.

Comment: you can use space or end of line along with non-greedy match `perl -pe 's/ SCYEXIT\(.*?\)( |$)/ /g'`

Comment: Sorry, put perl is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: can you add a sample input with all type of cases and corresponding output to the question? all the back and forth with words doesn't seem to explain your exact requirements.. and why is `perl` not an option? which OS are you using?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I'll add more examples soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
$ cat ip.txt 
SCYEXIT(' ')
DEFINE QLOCAL ('postcard') SCYEXIT('/var/mqm/exits/SecExitSender(SecurityExit)') PROCESS(' ') PUT(ENABLED) DEFPRTY(0) REPLACE
PROCESS(' ') asd
1 SCYEXIT(' ')
PROCESS(' ')
DEFINE QLOCAL ('postcard')
```

Solution using `sed`

```sh
$ sed -E 's/(SCYEXIT|PROCESS)\(\S+\)//g ; s/(SCYEXIT|PROCESS)\(.\s*.\)//g' ip.txt

DEFINE QLOCAL ('postcard')   PUT(ENABLED) DEFPRTY(0) REPLACE
 asd
1 

DEFINE QLOCAL ('postcard')
```

- `(SCYEXIT|PROCESS)\(\S+\)` means `SCYEXIT` or `PROCESS` followed by `(` and then one or more non-whitespace characters and ending with `)`
- `(SCYEXIT|PROCESS)\(.\s*.\)` means `SCYEXIT` or `PROCESS` followed by `(` and then any character, any number of whitespaces, another character and finally `)` --> this takes care of empty brackets case
- Use `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]` instead of `\s` and `\S` for non-GNU versions

If `perl` is available,

```sh
perl -pe 's/(SCYEXIT|PROCESS)\(.*?\)( |$)//g' ip.txt
```

which gives same output as `sed` solution except for deleting space after ending bracket of `SCYEXIT` or `PROCESS` if present

Comment: Thanks @sp-asic, this is it.
I have to wrap my head around to fully understand but for now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':a 
    s/([^()][^()]*)//g
    t a'
```

use [^()] instead of [^)], and do substitutions repeatedly until there is no pair of matching braces.

Comment: Thanks @pdg, but this does not work at all because the optional second brackets is enclosed in the first bracket.

Comment: @Nicolaie yes it works for enclosed brackets. `a(b(c(e f)g)h))ijl` yields `a)ijl` (notice the unbalanced closing parenthesis is preserved).